# TFS RM 2015 Build retention policy is not working some times

Tags: tfs-2015, retention

We are using TFS RM 2015 Update 4.

Build Retention policy is working for most of builds. But, it is ignoring some builds. Existing documentation has only basic info, do you have more detailed rules for build retention policy

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have set the **Release retention policy** which conflicts/interact with the **Build retention policy**.

> **Interaction between build and release retention**
>
> The build linked to a release has its own retention policy, which may
>   be shorter than that of the release. If you want to retain the build
>   for the same period as the release, set the **Retain build** checkbox
>   for the appropriate environments. **This overrides the retention policy
>   for the build**, and ensures that the artifacts are available if you
>   need to redeploy that release.

Please see [Build and release retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention?view=vsts) for details.